# In ΔABC , AC=BC and ∠C=20∘ . M is on side AC and N is on side BC .

Tags: geometry

In ΔABC, AC=BC and ∠C=20∘. M is on side AC and N is on side BC such that ∠BAN=50∘ and ∠ABM=60∘. Find ∠NMB

I have checked up the previous answers to this question but they included trigonometry.
Can someone help me solve this with elementary geometry?

[My Approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tvKN.png)

This is my approach, I've tried basic angle chasing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What's the point of having two links to the same image?

Comment: Did that by mistake.

Comment: $\angle C=120$ or $\angle C=20$

Comment: Straightforward solution is with using trigonometry, insight solution is with using additional construction.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Can you please explain it to me with the additional construction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

$AB=BN$ (isosceles $\triangle$)

Draw $BD$ such that $\angle ABD = 20^o$ then $BA=BD$ and $BD=BN$

Draw $DN$ then $\triangle BDN$ is an equilateral triangle

Then $\angle DBM = 40^o$ and $\angle DMB = 40^o$ then $DM=DB$ (isosceles $\triangle$)

Finally, $DN=DM$ (isosceles $\triangle$) and $\angle DMN = 70^o$ hence $\angle BMN = 30^o$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let add point D which is symmetric to N with respect to AC. Triangle AND is equilateral. BD is perpendicular bisector of AN. Then BD is bisector of angle ABN. Then angle CBD is 40°. Due to symmetry angle DCB is 40°. Then BCD is isosceles triangle. Then D lies on line EM which is perpendicular bisector of BC. Then angle EDB is 50°. Then angle MDN is 20°. Then angle MND is 20°. Then angle EMN is 40°. Note that angle EMB is 70°. Then angle NMB is 30°.

Comment: What do we mean by symmetric, with respect to AC?

Comment: Also, how do we make a construction assumption, I mean considering what parameters?

Comment: D is symmetric to N with respect to line AC when DN is perpendicular to AC and line AC crosses DN in the middle of DN. D is unique, so there are no assumption. "We just add to the picture point D and then try to use it to obtain what needed". Quoted sentence relates to solution  of Lion Heart too.